# java spring mvc instantiating DispatcherServlet error

Tags: java, spring-mvc, instantiation

Instantiating DispatcherServlet fails.

[image]

I checked and org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.class is in spring-webmvc-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar which is in WEB-INF's lib folder.

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

<display-name>PizzaOrderApp</display-name>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springfamework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd">


<bean   id="HandlerMapping"  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping"/>

<bean name="/" class="com.pizzaorder.controller.PizzaOrder" />


<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>


</beans>
```

Any advice what to check further?
I guess it will be something with namespaces in web.xml, not in the build path.
Thanks

Comment: You import the spring api properly ? I suggest STS https://spring.io/tools and perhaps use maven

Comment: could you advise how and where to check if spring api is imported properly?
the jar-s are in the lib of web-inf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be missing an "r" in framework:

org.springfamework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
org.springf**r**amework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet

Comment: thanks. i havent noticed my typo.
now works as expected.